# Holy stone HS130D PCB part details

Tags: design, electronics, toy-grade-drone

[image]Any idea where to get individual PCB parts info for fixing a Holystone HS130D PCB. It looks like two adjacent units in PCB have heated up and melted together causing one motor to keep running without input. I am not great with electronics but trying to fix this drone.

Answer (score 0):

You can usually find electronic components easily enough on ebay, or any of the big electronic suppliers. The problem is working out exactly what it is, especially once any label has burnt off. The manufacturer probably doesn't publish documentation at that level. It's not in their interest to help anyone do repairs like this, they'd much rather you buy a new one. Also they don't want to give their competitors all the information they'd need to copy it.

It's possible that there are four identical components in a row. If so, you might be able to read the label from one of the unburnt ones, and use that to track down a new one.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will have to trash it and look for new one as you also suggested.